# How to unmute HTML 5 video when clicking Full Screen mode

Tags: html, video

I have a HTML video that autoplays muted on entering the website, what I am trying to achieve is that when a user clicks the Full Screen button on the controls the video will go back to the beginning and play out loud, any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

I assume you have something like this:

```
<video autoplay muted controls ...>
  <source src="video.mp4" type="video/mp4">
  ...
</video>
```

What you need is `fullscreenchange` event handler:

```
var video = document.querySelector('video');
video.addEventListener(
  'fullscreenchange',
  function(e) {
    if (document.fullscreenEnabled) {
      video.muted = false;
      video.currentTime = 0;
    }
  }
);
```

For more information about Fullscreen API, check this [page](https://dvcs.w3.org/hg/fullscreen/raw-file/tip/Overview.html).

**Note:** keep in mind vendor specific prefixes.